# How-to generate a Java class from a WSDL with a deprecated annotation?

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, cxf, deprecated

In the project I'm working on we have several WSDL considered as interfaces.
We are generating Java code from the WSDLs/XSDs.

The problem is that I have to remove one of the interface, but prior to that I want to generate the class with the @deprecated annotation.

I have yet some WSDL bindings and XSD bindings files, but with only default JAXB properties (mainly package naming and generateIsSetMethod).

I use cxf-codegen-plugin with maven 2.

Answer (score 1):

Using the annox plugin, I'm now able to mark as deprecated the parameter wrappers used for in and/or out of the methods in the WSDL.

Using the documentation tag in portType the WSDL I can't use the @deprecated Javadoc annotation to mark as deprecated the interfaces. (But only in Javadoc).

I'm looking for more:

- Mark as deprecated (in the code) the interface
- Mark as deprecated the client stubs that are generated.

Comment: can you post the example of what you did to get this to work? I have the same question but I don't get how this answers it.

Comment: Project is Open source, so you can have a look. This http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=weblab&path=%2Ftrunk%2FWebLabExchangeModel%2Fmodel%2Fschemas%2Fbindings%2Fxsd-bindings.xml links to the binding files. If you check reportprovier (which was one of our deprecated interface) you should find the annox configuration.